# Compare array of objects (image) and span tags (image)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I want to compare array of object(image) and span tag(image). on the button click i need to check whether the dropped image and span image is equal or not. so kindly help me on this.

component.html:

```
 <div class="field-box-samp">
        <div class="captchaText">
          <span id="circle_text"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/1.png"></span>
          <span id="triangle_text"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/2.png"></span>
          <span id="square_text"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/3.png"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts:

```
    origin = [{    
    img: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png'
  },
  {    
      img: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png'
  },
  {   
      img: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/3.png'
  }];
  //---------------

  destination = [
  ];
  //--------------- 
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      let item:any = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
      let copy:any = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
      let element:any = {};
        for(let attr in copy){
          if(attr == 'title'){
            element[attr] = copy[attr] += ' copy';
          }else{
            element[attr] = copy[attr];
          }
        }
      this.destination=[element];
      clearimg()        
    }
   }  
  }
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What do you wish to compare? Do you want to know if the images in the array are already present in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

```
const imageNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.captchaText img');
const origin = [{ img: '1' }, { img: '2' }, { img: '3' }];

const isMatch = Array.from(imageNodes).every((img, idx) => img.src === origin[idx].image);

if (isMatch) {
  // business logic ;)
}
```

Comment: i have update my question. can you please check it nw. i need to check this (this.destination=[element];) with span image.

Comment: Reviewer here. I won't recommend deletion but please add details to your answer describing why your code is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check that your existing span contains images present in ur origin object.

```
// dont use 'origin' it is also an keyword in js
    let originUrl = [{    
        img: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/1.png'
      },
      {    
          img: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/2.png'
      },
      {   
          img: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/3.png'
      }];
    const matchSpanFn = spanID => {
        let isExist = false;
        for (var i in originUrl) {
             if (originUrl[i].img === document.querySelectorAll('#'+spanID+' img')[0].getAttribute('src'))
                isExist = true
        }
        return isExist

        }

    matchSpanFn('circle_text') // here you can pass any id to check with constant node structure as shown above
```

Comment: i have update my question. can you please check it nw.

Comment: i need to check this (this.destination=[element];) with span image.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and match all.

based on update.

```
/*
const origin = [
  { img: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/1.png" },
  { img: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/2.png" },
  { img: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/3.png" }
];
*/
function matchImages(domImages, destination) {
  return destination.some((item, index) => item.img === domImages[index].src);
}

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  } else {
    let item:any = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
    let copy:any = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
    let element:any = {};
      for(let attr in copy){
        if(attr == 'title'){
          element[attr] = copy[attr] += ' copy';
        }else{
          element[attr] = copy[attr];
        }
      }
    let allImages = document.querySelectorAll(".captchaText span img");
    this.destination=[element];
    const hasMatchingImage = matchImages(allImages, this.destination)
    console.log("Has a MatchingImage", hasMatchingImage);

    clearimg()        
  }
 }
```

```js
let allImages = document.querySelectorAll(".captchaText span img");
const origin = [
  { img: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/1.png" },
  { img: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/2.png" },
  { img: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/3.png" }
];

const hasSame = origin.every(
  (item, index) => item.img === allImages[index].src
);
console.log("All Same", hasSame);
```

```html
<div class="field-box-samp">
            <div class="captchaText">
              <span id="circle_text"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/1.png"></span>
              <span id="triangle_text"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/2.png"></span>
              <span id="square_text"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/galler/3.png"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: i have update my question. can you please check it nw. i need to check this (this.destination=[element];) with span image.

Comment: i have tried your code but am facing some issue. so kindly check the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964256/making-drag-and-drop-elementimage-while-dropping-i-want-to-compare-the-eleme

Comment: its working fine for origin but its not working for destination...for the first image its showing true even its not a same image but its showing false for other two even it is same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about TS, but you can do this with vanilla JS. You can compare the URLs like this and then push all the matching URLs to a new array and all the non matching URLs to another array:

```
const allSpanImges = [...document.querySelectorAll('span img')];

let match = [];
let noMatch = [];

allSpanImges.forEach((spanImg, index) => {
    spanImg.src.localeCompare(origin[index].img) ? match.push(spanImg.src) : noMatch.push(spanImg.src)
});

console.log(match)
```